# How to map JSON to an object with a different structure?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some JSON with this schema:

```
{
    "person":{
        "name":"test",
        "family":"testi"
    },
    "Employee":{
        "id":54,
        "department":"web development",
        "skils":[{"type":"C#", "grade":"good"},{{"type":"SQL", "grade":"Expert"}}]
    }
}
```

and I need to map this JSON to following classes:

```
class Employee {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public Skill[] Skills { get; set;}
}

class skill {
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

Now is there any way to map my JSON schema to my C# object?
I am using the Newtonsoft.Json library and am trying to use the `JsonProperty` attribute like this:

```
[JsonProperty("Person.Name")]
```

on my `Employee` class.  But this does not work.  Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your class is not proper for your json. You must equalize properties of class and properties of json object.
Your json has a property named person but your class does not have it.

```
MappedObject mappedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MappedObject>(yourJson);

class MappedObject{
    public Person person;
    public Employee employee; 
}

class Person{
    public string name;
    public string family;
}
class Employee {
    public intid{get; set;}
    public string deartment {get; set;}
    public Skill[] skills {get; set;}
}
class skill{
    public string type{get; set;}
    public string grade{get; set;}
}
```

OR better way you can use dynamic object.

```
dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJson);
```

Comment: i do this ... ant it work very well... my project is a wrapper for other service and i must send object with my own schema.... i can use auto mapper but this cause create an extra step to convert MappedObject to my schema. I want to reduce this step

Comment: So you should use my first code.

Comment: but it does not fill employee name and family Property ....

Comment: So you can send or use mappedObject.employee but you have to fill them from your json. after filling you do not use them.

Comment: There is an error in the `Employee` class. It still contains the `Name` and `Family` property - which are not part of the inital json schema. And - for sake of successful mapping - capitalization of the properties names should be consistent.